# How spark streaming identifies new files

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How does spark streaming `fileStream` identifies new files in the monitoring directory from one interval to another interval?

Is it based on on the new file names or the file creation timestamp or any other approach?

What is the significance of `newFilesOnly` argument?

```
fileStream(String directory, Class<K> kClass, Class<V> vClass, Class<F> fClass, Function<org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,Boolean> filter, boolean newFilesOnly, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf)
```

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer on the monitoring is that it uses the file modification time (`isNewFile` uses `getFileModTime`)

As to `newFilesOnly`....that is not that straight forward, but you can [discern this info from the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/FileInputDStream.scala).

The TL;DR; is that it only pulls old files (`newFilesOnly = false`) from the last minute from streaming start.

The more complicated answer with this argument is that it sets a value `initialModTimeIgnoreThreshold` to be the current time or 0. This value is then used to set the `modTimeIgnoreThreshold`, which is the max of the above versus the oldest file that is in the search time window (`currentTime - durationToRemember.milliseconds`). That is where an [existing bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3276) was [JUST fixed](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/c25ca7c5a1f2a4f88f40b0c5cdbfa927c186cfa8). The time window used to be a hard coded one minute window, so you could only ever get files modified within the last 1 minute if you set this argument to false. I am still skeptical about this fix though...But, either way, this argument was essentially broken until 3 days ago.